# Creating service for nodejs app in Oracle linux

Tags: node.js, linux, service

I have a nodejs app and I want to run it as a a service in oracle linux server. 
I have created the service file /etc/init.d/wsdlsrv and after that i run this commands:

```
cd /etc/init.d
chmod +x wsdlsrv
/sbin/chkconfig wsdlsrv on
systemctl start wsdlsrv
```

The wsdlsrv code is the following:

```
user="root"
. /etc/init.d/functions
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin/:$PATH"  
name='wsdlsrv'
pid_file="/var/run/$name.pid" 
stdout_log="/var/log/$name.log"
stderr_log="/var/log/$name.err"
get_pid() {
    cat "$pid_file"
}
is_running() {
    [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}
case "$1" in
    start)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Already started"
    else
        echo "Starting $name"
        cd "/home/wsdlsrv"
            su $user -c "node app" >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &

        echo $! > "$pid_file"
        if ! is_running; then
            echo "Unable to start, see $stdout_log and $stderr_log"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    ;;
    stop)
    if is_running; then
        echo -n "Stopping $name.."
        kill `get_pid`
        for i in {1..10}
        do
            if ! is_running; then
                break
            fi

            echo -n "."
            sleep 1
        done
        echo

        if is_running; then
            echo "Not stopped; may still be shutting down or shutdown may have failed"
            exit 1
        else
            echo "Stopped"
                if [ -f "$pid_file" ]; then
                rm "$pid_file"
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Not running"
    fi
    ;;
    restart)
    $0 stop
    if is_running; then
        echo "Unable to stop, will not attempt to start"
        exit 1
    fi
    $0 start
    ;;
    status)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Running"
    else
        echo "Stopped"
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

But when i try to start the service with systemclt it throws and error: Job for wsdlsrv.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status wsdlsrv.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.Job for wsdlsrv.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status wsdlsrv.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: That means that your nodejs app returned a code other than 0. I browsed through the init.d script (which, you should probably stop using if possible and use a systemd.service script under /lib/systemd/system/wsdlsrv.service btw) and it seems ok. You should run the nodejs app in the same manner to verify that it's working properly outside of sysvinit first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `service wsdlsrv start` ?

Make sure you have atleast empty file entry at /etc/sysconfig/wsdlsrv

```
[root@centos ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/wsdlsrv 
# TODO: add relevant configuration stuff here.
```

Then you need to reload systemctl daemon by executing `systemctl daemon-reload`.
After this you can use `systemctl status wsdlsrv` , `systemctl start wsdlsrv` etc.

Ex:

```
[root@centos init.d]# systemctl status wsdlsrv
● wsdlsrv.service - (null)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/wsdlsrv; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-03-14 17:12:47 EDT; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Mar 14 17:12:47 centos systemd[1]: Starting (null)...
Mar 14 17:12:47 centos systemd[1]: wsdlsrv.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Mar 14 17:12:47 centos systemd[1]: Failed to start (null).
Mar 14 17:12:47 centos systemd[1]: Unit wsdlsrv.service entered failed state.
Mar 14 17:12:47 centos systemd[1]: wsdlsrv.service failed.
```

You can use `journalctl -xe` to see the error messages from systemd